# JBoss 7.1 Database based JAAS authentication - authentication failed

Tags: java, security, jboss7.x, jaas

I am trying to implement database based JAAS authentication on JBoss 7.1 Application server, but getting below error. Any pointer will be helpful.

I have shared configuration details.

> 14:46:03,807 TRACE
>   [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) **Obtained user password** 14:46:03,808
>   DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) AppDS: returnConnection(40c2d8ac,
>   false) [1/9] 14:46:03,808 TRACE
>   [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) resumeAnyTransaction 14:46:03,808
>   TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) **User 'test_user' authenticated,
>   loginOk=true** 14:46:03,808 TRACE
>   [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) abort 14:46:03,809 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) **Login failure:
>   javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password
>   Incorrect/Password Required at**
>   org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:293)
>   [picketbox-4.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.9.Final-redhat-1] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449)
>   [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
>   at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383)
>   [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
>   at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371)
>   [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
>   at
>   org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160)
>   [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.9.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.0.9.Final-redhat-1]
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1] at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:381)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1] at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_2.dtd">

<jboss-web>
    <!-- <security-domain>java:/jaas/apsapp</security-domain> -->
     <security-domain>other</security-domain>
    <context-root>/app</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

**web.xml**

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured Content</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
        <role-name>AUTHENTICATED</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>AUTHENTICATED</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**Standalone.xml**

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/appPgDS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd from app.user where username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role,'Roles' from app.userrole where username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                            <module-option name="hashCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

**login.xhtml**

```
 <form id="loginForm" action="j_security_check" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="j_username"  value="test_user" maxlength="22" />
        <input type="password" name="j_password" value="password" maxlength="22" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

**Password Generated**

```
import org.jboss.security.auth.spi.*;

String passwordHash = Util.createPasswordHash("MD5", "base64", null, null, "password");
//Value generated and stored in DB: X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==
```

Comment: Have you verified that you have stored the correct Base64-Encoded, UTF-8 MD5 hashes in your database

Comment: @Flo: yes verified password. Included password generation script above

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25612527/2490834 a similar issue and my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I commented out the below statements which was appearing as default in standalone.xml.

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
<login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
</login-module>
<login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
</login-module>
```