# Method invocation failure JAX-RS / Wildfly / Java SDK13 with interceptor

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I've added an interceptor to my JAX-RS / Resteasy Java SDK13 project running on Wildfly 18 in order to use annotations (e.g. @RolesAllowed).  While the security implementation is way better than the programmatic approach, I'm getting an invocation error when Resteasy tries to call the matched function (deleteAll()). I've traced through the Interceptor flow just prior to the attempted invocation and the Interceptor **approves** the user and passes control onward. Then I get this error, which seems to be a security failure, despite my interceptor having approved the user.

I changed the Wildfly setting 
`<default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>` but this hasn't changed the behavior.

Java Source being called with `/consumers/deleteall` with nothing in the body and no query string.

**Security Interceptor**

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class SecurityInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
   private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
   private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "xxx";
   private static final ServerResponse ACCESS_DENIED = new ServerResponse("Access denied for this resource", 401, new Headers<Object>());;
   private static final ServerResponse ACCESS_FORBIDDEN = new ServerResponse("Nobody can access this resource", 403, new Headers<Object>());;
   private static final ServerResponse SERVER_ERROR = new ServerResponse("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", 500, new Headers<Object>());;

   @Inject
   private GenericUserDAO guDAO;

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
   {
       ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) requestContext.getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");
       Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();

       if (method != null)
           System.out.println("Access attempt to "+method.getName());

       //Access allowed for all 
       if( ! method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class))
       {
           //Access denied for all 
           if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class))
           {
               requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
               return;
           }

           //Get request headers
           final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();

           //Fetch authorization header
           final List<String> authorization = headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);

           //If no authorization information present; block access
           if(authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty())
           {
               requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
               return;
           }

           //Get encoded username and password
           final String token = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");

           //Verify user access
           if(method.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class))
           {
               RolesAllowed rolesAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
               Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(rolesAnnotation.value()));

               //Is user valid?
               if( ! isUserAllowed(token, rolesSet))
               {
                   requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println("approved");
   }


   private boolean isUserAllowed(final String token, final Set<String> rolesSet) 
   {
       User user = guDAO.findUserByToken(token);
       if (user.getClass() == SuperUser.class)
           return true;

       String userRole = user.getClass().getSimpleName();
       System.out.println("User role is "+userRole+"    Role set is "+rolesSet.toString());
       return rolesSet.contains(userRole);
   }

}
```

**JAX_RS Handlers**

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@Path("/consumers")
@RolesAllowed({"SuperUser","Consumer"})
public class ConsumerEndpoint extends UserEndpoint {

    /**
     * Delete all consumers
     * @param token
     * @return
     */
    @DELETE
    @Path("/deleteall")
    @RolesAllowed({"SuperUser","Consumer"})
    public Response deleteAll() {
        Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;

        if (!consumerDAO.deleteAll()) {
            Map<String, String> responseObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
            responseObj.put("error", "Error executing deletion");
            builder = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(responseObj);
            return builder.build();
        }

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

**LOG DATA**

```
23:29:23,661 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ConsumerEndpoint for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.eventhorizon.eva.rest.responder.ConsumerEndpoint.deleteAll(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.eventhorizon.eva.rest.responder.ConsumerEndpoint.deleteAll() of bean: ConsumerEndpoint is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)


23:29:23,665 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /eva/rest/consumers/deleteall: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.eventhorizon.eva.rest.responder.ConsumerEndpoint.deleteAll() of bean: ConsumerEndpoint is not allowed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:456)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.eventhorizon.eva.rest.responder.ConsumerEndpoint.deleteAll() of bean: ConsumerEndpoint is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:627)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at deployment.eva.war//com.eventhorizon.eva.rest.responder.ConsumerEndpoint$$$view8.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:317)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    ... 59 more

23:29:23,670 INFO  [io.undertow.request.dump] (default task-1) 
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/eva/rest/consumers/deleteall
 characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=0
       contentType=[application/json]
            header=Accept=application/json
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Authorization=ApiKey-v1 AC0gP9D-2jrCRDXfzyTayDb5LuUTTX9_Z2NwMDcwM0BnbWFpbC5jb20=
            header=Content-Type=application/json
            header=Content-Length=0
            header=User-Agent=Java/13.0.1
            header=Host=localhost:8080
            locale=[]
            method=DELETE
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=/127.0.0.1:53053
        remoteHost=localhost
            scheme=http
              host=localhost:8080
        serverPort=8080
          isSecure=false
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=-1
       contentType=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Transfer-Encoding=chunked
            header=Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Date=Tue, 14 Jan 2020 06:29:23 GMT
            status=500

==============================================================
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.eventhorizon</groupId>
    <artifactId>eva</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Eva REST Interface</name>
    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- You can reference property in pom.xml or filtered resources (must 
            enable third-party plugin if using Maven < 2.1) -->

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->

        <version.jboss.maven.plugin>7.9.Final</version.jboss.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>1.0.7.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <!-- Other dependency versions -->
        <version.org.eclipse.m2e>1.0.0</version.org.eclipse.m2e>
        <version.ro.isdc.wro4j>1.4.4</version.ro.isdc.wro4j>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.2</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.bom/wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools-builder -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools-builder</artifactId>
                <version>18.0.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee/jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec-parent -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <!-- <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> -->
        <finalName>eva</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an EJB (`@LocalBean`) annotation. And you applied `@RolesAllowed` annotation. This means, your EJB / REST service invocation is automatically protected by the JEE runtime.

Basically, what you are doing in your interceptor is already performed by Wildfly. But in a different way. Now you accidentally have two ways or levels of authentication. I suggest you stick to a single implementation.

Either you go with JAAS framework or use your custom interceptor. You should not use both at the same time.

1. My recommended approach would be to setup a JAAS Login module in Wildfly. There should be plenty of examples of how to do that, e.g. use https://docs.wildfly.org/18/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#Database_Authentication_Migration or [JBoss Wildfly - database login module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291407/jboss-wildfly-database-login-module)
2. Do not use JAAS and provide your custom security interceptor. Basically you could keep your interceptor class. In order to make it work, you could use your own set of annotations to check for access.