# How to secure JAX-RS RESTful Web Services in WildFly 9 with JAAS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs, wildfly, jaas

I have done simple authorization and authentication using `JAAS` without application server. So now i was wondering is it possible to secure `JAX-RS` web services in `jboss` with `JAAS`. I want user in order to login they provide their email and password and then authorize the user else display error.
A working example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JBoss 7.1 Database based JAAS authentication - authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458316/jboss-7-1-database-based-jaas-authentication-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 0):

For JBoss in general you need the following:

- a security domain say mydomain defined in the standalone XML
- all the JBoss modules required by the JAAS module for the mydomain security domain to be defined.
- the mydomain defined as the security domain the web.xml of the web
  application.

Debugging tip add the following to your standalone XML:

```
<logger category="org.jboss.security">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

The above will put debugging information in all phases of the authorisation and authentication flow for JAAS used by your application.